# Why is last button/task removed in this code?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I have a block of code which is called on a button press.  The aim is to remove the task the button represents, and update all the other buttons to reflect the time changes.  The function take an argument pos which is the position in the list of tasks to remove.  That task entry is removed and the remaining task times updated.

The buttons are all removed and re-placed with new times and positions etc.

```
def remove_task(self, pos, *args):
        print("\nRemoving task...")
        print("List size = " + str(len(self.scheduled_tasks)))
        print("Task pos = " + str(pos))
        print("Task name = " + str(self.scheduled_tasks[pos].name))
        del self.scheduled_tasks[pos] #Task deleted from list
        print("Task deleted!")
        print("Tasks:")
        for task in self.scheduled_tasks:
            print(task.name)
        print("Re-assigning task n values...")
        for index, tasks in enumerate(self.scheduled_tasks):
            print("Index = " + str(index))
            self.scheduled_tasks[index].n = int(index)
            print("Name: " + str(self.scheduled_tasks[index].name))
            print("N = " + str(self.scheduled_tasks[index].n))
        print("N assingments complete")

        print("List size = " + str(len(self.scheduled_tasks)))
        for i in self.scheduled_tasks:
            print("Task " + str(i.n) + " = " + str(i.name))
        print("Deleting buttons...")
        print("Number of buttons = " + str(len(self.ids.schedule.children)))
        self.ids.schedule.clear_widgets()
        print("Buttons deleted!")

        position = 0
        for i in self.scheduled_tasks:
            print("Creating new buttons...")
            if i.n == 0:
                print("First button")
                print("I.n = "+ str(i.n))
                task_name = self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].name
                print("Name = " + task_name)
                task_time = self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].size
                print("Task time = " + str(task_time))
                parent_size = self.day
                initial = App.get_running_app().user_start_time
                end = initial + task_time
                print("Task end time = " + str(end))
                self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].set_start_time(initial)
                self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].set_end_time(end)
                print("New times set!")
                if self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].class_type == "task":
                    print("Finding task size...")
                    self.task_size = self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].decimal_size
                    print("Size = " + str(self.task_size))
                    button_size = 1/int(parent_size/self.task_size)
                    print("Button_size = " + str(button_size))
                    task_type = self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].type
                    self.rgba = set_task_color(task_type, self.task_name).split(",")
                if self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].class_type == "break":
                    button_size = 1/(self.parent_size/(self.break_size_init/60))
                    self.rgba = [0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]
                print("Position = " + str(position))
                self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].n = position
                position = position + 1
                print("Position in scheduled tasks = " + str(self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].n))
                task_button = Button(text = task_name + "\n" + str(self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].start_time.strftime("%H:%M")) + "\n - \n" + str(self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].end_time.strftime("%H:%M")),
                                        size_hint = (button_size, 0.5),
                                        text_size = (None, None),
                                        font_size = 12,
                                        pos_hint = {"top": 1},
                                        background_normal = "white",
                                        background_color = self.rgba)
                task_button.text_size = task_button.size
                task_button.halign = "center"
                task_button.n = self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].n
                print("Button position = " + str(task_button.n))
                task_button.bind(on_release = lambda x: self.ids.schedule.remove_widget(task_button))
                if self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].class_type == "task":
                    task_button.bind(on_release = lambda x: self.remove_task(i.n))
                elif self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].class_type == "break":
                    task_button.bind(on_release = lambda x: self.remove_break(i.n))
                print("Button functions bound")
                self.ids.schedule.add_widget(task_button)
            else:
                print("Subsequent button")
                print("I = " + str(i.n))
                task_name = self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].name
                print("Name = " + task_name)
                print("Calculating times...")
                initial = self.scheduled_tasks[i.n-1].end_time
                end = initial + self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].size
                print("Assigning times...")
                self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].set_start_time(initial)
                self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].set_end_time(end)
                print("New times set!")
                if self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].class_type == "task":
                    c.execute("SELECT Size FROM Tasks WHERE Name = ?;", (self.task_name,))
                    task_size_raw = "".join(c for c in str(str(c.fetchall())) if c not in "[](''`),")
                    self.task_size = float(task_size_raw) #hours, decimal
                    button_size = 1/int(parent_size/self.task_size)
                    task_type = self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].type
                    self.rgba = set_task_color(task_type, self.task_name).split(",")
                if self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].class_type == "break":
                    button_size = 1/(self.parent_size/(self.break_size_init/60))
                    self.rgba = [0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]
                position = position + 1
                print("position = " + str(self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].n))
                task_button = Button(text = task_name + "\n" + str(self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].start_time.strftime("%H:%M")) + "\n - \n" + str(self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].end_time.strftime("%H:%M")),
                                        size_hint = (button_size, 0.5),
                                        text_size = (None, None),
                                        font_size = 12,
                                        pos_hint = {"top": 1},
                                        background_normal = "white",
                                        background_color = self.rgba)
                task_button.text_size = task_button.size
                task_button.halign = "center"
                task_button.n = i.n
                print("Button position = " + str(task_button.n))
                task_button.bind(on_release = lambda x: self.ids.schedule.remove_widget(task_button))
                if self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].class_type == "task":
                    task_button.bind(on_release = lambda x: self.remove_task(i.n))
                elif self.scheduled_tasks[i.n].class_type == "break":
                    task_button.bind(on_release = lambda x: self.remove_break(i.n))
                print("Button functions bound")
                self.ids.schedule.add_widget(task_button)
                print("Done!" + "\n")
        print("Buttons created!")
        print("Re-ordering complete!" + "\n")
```

Removing a task in the first instance works but when removing any later tasks/buttons the last task is always removed.  The code output shows the button function is correctly bound to call the correct position argument but then always removes the last button/last entry in the list of tasks.

Output:

```
Removing task...
List size = 3
Task pos = 1 #Correct position
Task name = Test2
Task deleted!
Tasks:
Test
Test3
Re-assigning task n values...
Index = 0
Name: Test
N = 0
Index = 1
Name: Test3
N = 1
N assingments complete
List size = 2
Task 0 = Test
Task 1 = Test3
Deleting buttons...
Number of buttons = 3
Buttons deleted!
Creating new buttons...
First button
I.n = 0
Name = Test
Task time = 2:00:00
Task end time = 2021-01-03 16:30:00
New times set!
Finding task size...
Size = 2.0
Button_size = 0.5
0.8943980039499027,0.2144472118229821,0.011421795014607938,0.7
Position = 0
Position in scheduled tasks = 0
Button position = 0
Button functions bound
Creating new buttons...
Subsequent button
I = 1
Name = Test3
Calculating times...
Assigning times...
New times set!
0.8943980039499027,0.2144472118229821,0.011421795014607938,0.7
position = 1
Button position = 1
Button functions bound
Done!

Buttons created!
Re-ordering complete!

#^First removal, works fine with no issues^

Removing task...
List size = 2
Task pos = 1 #I clicked the button for the first task (Task 0) and this position argument was given!
Task name = Test3
Task deleted!
Tasks:
Test
Re-assigning task n values...
Index = 0
Name: Test
N = 0
N assingments complete
List size = 1
Task 0 = Test
Deleting buttons...
Number of buttons = 2
Buttons deleted!
Creating new buttons...
First button
I.n = 0
Name = Test
Task time = 2:00:00
Task end time = 2021-01-03 16:30:00
New times set!
Finding task size...
Size = 2.0
Button_size = 0.5
0.8943980039499027,0.2144472118229821,0.011421795014607938,0.7
Position = 0
Position in scheduled tasks = 0
Button position = 0
Button functions bound
Buttons created!
Re-ordering complete!


Removing task...
List size = 1
Task pos = 0
Task name = Test
Task deleted!
Tasks:
Re-assigning task n values...
N assingments complete
List size = 0
Deleting buttons...
Number of buttons = 1
Buttons deleted!
Buttons created!
Re-ordering complete!

#^Second and all subsequent removals remove the last task^
```

Can anybody see why the button is calling the last task instance to be removed?  Why does every button after one task is correctly removed call for the last task to be removed?

I appreciate this is a long and detailed question so thanks in advance for any of your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by binding a partial function instead of lambda to call the function on the button press.  So instead of `lambda x: remove_task(i.n)` it would be `partial(remove_task,i.n)`